# Highlights Panel never shows action icons?

Tags: lightning-web-components, action, lightning-quickaction, highlights-panel

I want to check if I'm missing something or if the "Highlights Panel" component that allows custom actions to be added just does not (by design) show custom action icons. I assume the latter; please confirm or let me know what I'm missing here.

(Would be good if it did - a long row of text-only custom buttons looks pretty dull.)

Here is my custom action with a red icon referenced via a static resource:

[image: action definition including icon]

and here is the action presented **without** the icon:

[image: Highlights panel button]

Comment: Can't find anything saying it definitively but I've never seen an icon on the highlights panel in desktop and all quick actions have an icon set by default when you create one (lightning bolt). Only see the icon in mobile or in the global actions dropdown.

Comment: Thanks @KrisGoncalves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on no-one saying otherwise, look like in Dec 2021:

```
Highlights Panel never shows action icons
```

(And see Kris's comment about other contexts.)